# Identifiy this Visual Studio sign, please

Tags: visual-studio, identify

I must have pressed a wrong keyboard combo and got this little arrow sign in my Visual Studio 2019, left of the code, where breakpoints reside. Could not find any way to identify it. Google image search and Bing Visual Search could not find anything.
So, what is this, please? [image: unknown symbol]

Ok, a broader view in context: [image]

Restarting VS made is disappear, but now I am so curious, what feature is this?

Comment: Doesn't have a tooltip when hovered?

Comment: No tooltip, no right-click menu, nothing. See answer below.

Comment: Google and Bing were so completely and utterly useless in this, I am still baffled. Google image search insisted on adding some random keywords, like 'vertical' and 'horizontal' (??) and displayed a wild variety of GUI elements as similar images. Bing on the other hand was simply 'Err.. dunno'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a [task list](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/using-the-task-list) shortcut. You can toggle it with `Ctrl+K, Ctrl+H`. You can open a task list window with `Ctrl+\, T`

Comment: I must have pressed it instead of Ctrl-M-H (Hide selected text). Just look down to your keyboard :)

Answer (score 1):

Its a Task List Shortcut

[Task List Shortcut Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/using-the-task-list?view=vs-2019#shortcuts)